# Capture Live Video from various Video Devices

Tags: c#, .net, video

I am not sure where I have to start to create .NET application (C#) to "Capture Live Video from various Video Devices."

Any clue?

Comment: There is a lot of topics on this even on SO: [tag:directshow.net]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a code project project that does what you are looking for using directx.

http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7123/Capture-Live-Video-from-various-Video-Devices

Comment: As I can this project is a very old (year 2004) Do u think the code is good for Windows 7/8 ?

Comment: If nothing else, it will serve as a starting point and a starting point is what you asked for.